# jQuery Validation to Restrict A Textbox to only dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery method or workaround that someone has found that will not let the user type anything but dd/mm/yyyy in a textbox ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A masked control will prevent anything but valid input from being entered: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Or you could try jquery validation, it is one of the most popular validation frameworks: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Both Good Resources, but is there anyway to force the dd/mm positions? Essentially I would want it to not allow this:

23/04/2010

But Allow This:

04/23/2010

Comment: hmm. You could add both a validation method which tests for valid dates and a mask.